# UIPopoverController not triggering delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uipopovercontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm trying to detect when a UIPopoverController gets dismissed, but it seems not to work properly, the methods are not getting called. This is my code for presenting the UIPopoverController:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
UIPopoverController  *popoverVC = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
popoverVC.delegate = self;
[popoverVC presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height) inView:[home view] permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

I'm trying to fire this method, but is not getting called:

```
- (void) popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *) popoverController;
```

And I'm indeed adding the delegate to the header:

```
@interface Map : UIView <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
```

I don't know what I'm missing out, is not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved it, but I just faced the same problem. I'm holding a instance of UIPopoverController in my Viewcontroller and had it this way:

```
self.popover.delegate = self;
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:wgtvc];
```

of course this doesn't work because I'm initializing the UIPopoverController AFTER setting the delegate, which overrides the delegate setting. So the correct way is to FIRST initialize the UIPopovercontroller and THEN setting the delegate

```
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:wgtvc];
self.popover.delegate = self;
```

Maybe you are reinitializing your UIPopoverController somewhere - just set the delegate again after reinitializing.

Hpoe this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out how to make it work, I'm posting it as an answer, it's a combination of this with other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out how to make it work.

1. I made a "global" variable for the class.

   ```
   self.popoverVC = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
   self.popoverVC.delegate = self;
   ```
2. Because it's an UIImagePickerController inside a UIPopoverController, I needed to listen to the UIImagePickerController for dismission too and combine both methods:

   ```
   - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;
   - (void) popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *) popoverController
   ```

So I can now detect when the UIPopoverController gets dismissed.